# Azure service fabric : Container images not refresh

Tags: azure, docker, azure-service-fabric

I have build and deployment created on visual studio online for an angular app created using asp.net core template. I create the images and deploy them to azure container repository and in the deployment of service fabric project, i just update the code and package versions.

Even though the container gets re-spawned, the images on the service fabric cluster are not refreshed. They only get refreshed post manually deleting them. Is there something wrong that i am doing?

Comment: Are you using an explicit version tag on your container image, or are you using the [latest] tag? If so, please use an explicit version. The orchestrator doesn't check if the image tagged 'latest' was changed in the repository, it just checks for an image with that tag.

Comment: Using the latest tag. Is there a way to parameterized the image name so that I can pass the build version?

Comment: Sure, for example, when using VSTS, you can use `$(Build.BuildId)` in the Docker-Compose build task, in `Additional Image Tags`, so every image gets tagged with the build ID that created it. Use a tokenize task to replace the image version in your manifest. https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use an explicit version tag on your container image, don't rely on the [latest] tag. Please use an explicit version. The orchestrator doesn't check if the image tagged 'latest' was changed in the repository, it just checks for an image with that tag.

To fix this when using VSTS, you can use $(Build.BuildId) in the Docker-Compose build task, in Additional Image Tags, so every image gets tagged with the build ID that created it. Use a [tokenize](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) task to replace the image version in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks Loek. Was able to get it working using the following in the application manifest.  <ImageOverrides>
   <Image Name="[ImageName]"/>
  </ImageOverrides> . The [ImageName] is the parameter. Kindly include this also in the answer.